# time zone api INVALID_REQUEST

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I can't seem to find what is causing this. I checked the url again and again and I can't seem to find what is wrong with it.

```
function setTime() {
min = $("#minutes").val();
hour = $("select").val();
odG = $("#odGodina").val();
doG = $("#doGodina").val();
dat = $("#datepicker").val();
dat = dat.split("/"); //mm.dd.YYYY
vreme = new Date(dat[2], dat[0], dat[1], hour, min);
sendInput(vreme);
}
function sendInput(time) {
console.log(time.getTime());
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location="+lat+","+lngt+"&timestamp="+time.getTime()+"&sensor=false";
var testResenje = $.ajax({ 
    url: url, 
    }).done(function(response) {
        offset = response.rawOffset / 3600 + response.dstOffset / 3600;
        sendResponse();
        console.log(offset);
    });}
```

The url that gets build is:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=44.7220401,21.175114500000063&timestamp=1455189900000&sensor=false

Is there a problem with the number of characters long and lat have?

Or is my function order bad?

EDIT: Turns out if i have one less character in timestamp it works. Does that mean I can't use current time?

Comment: Does the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro#Examples) work for you? [(it works for me)](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200)

Comment: It does, I found out that the length of timestamp is the problem. If i reduce it by one character it works

Comment: It works for me [with the current UNIX time](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1452908015) (from [this site (randomly chosen from a google search)](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/), looks like your have a timestamp of 1000x the current time.

Answer (score 6):

Google timezoneapi expects timestamp as seconds as how unix timestamp represents not milliseconds.

> timestamp specifies the desired time as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro.